# Change display of multiple authors in authoryear style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

For my master thesis, I'm using the authoryear style in biblatex, because all sources in my bibliography need to be arranged in alphabetical order based on the author's last name. For multiple works from the same author, the entries should be sorted chronologically. It works fine so far, but unfortunately, for multiple authors, the names are displayed like this:

Apostolik, Richard and Christopher Donohue

However, according to the specifications of my university, it should look like this:

Apostolik, Richard / Donohue, Christopher

Is it possible to customize the authoryearstyle in that way or is there another style which sorts by last name of the author and year, and displays the names in the way I need them to be?

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc, 
index=totoc, 
bibliography=totoc, parskip, 
12pt, headsepline=true, a4paper]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}

\begin{document}

Just some text\footcite{Test}.

\clearpage 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And my bib file looks like this:

```
@book{Test,
author = {Apostolik, Richard and Donohue, Christopher},
title = {Test title},
year = {2010}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recent version of `biblatex` you should use

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to compile it, I get an error message saying "Undefined control sequence. l.9 \DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash} The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed." ?!

Comment: @Masterthesisproblems That's why I said you need a recent version of `biblatex`. If can't update or don't want to try `\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}` instead.

Comment: Without the update, \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash} \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim} gives me a slash to seperate the authors, but the sorting (last name, given name) is only correct for the first author, the other author is still displayed as Christopher Donohue instead of Donohue, Christopher. Is it possible to change that, too?

Comment: @Masterthesisproblems Ah, you are using a *really* old system. In that case you need `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` instead of `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`.